# How to include many smaller binary files in git repo?

Tags: git, tfs

For an existing project up to now only the source files are in a git repo.

To create an installer additionally binary files are required, which changes rarely.
Unfortunately, these are several thousands smaller files (20-60 kB mostly).
Creating a separate git repo for testing showed that in multiple branches the binary files would be about 2GB overall.

To link the binary files to the current commit, the wish would be to get the source code and the required binary files in one common repo.

What would be the best way to handle this?

- git is not recomended for handling binary files
- git lfs is not recommended for handling lots of small files

Remark: git lfs is already in use for some 3rd party libraries in the source repo.

Comment: Are the binary files expected to change? Would you categorize them as source files from this perspective?

Comment: No, the binary files changes rarely. Maybe every 2nd year as a mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No, the binary files changes rarely. Maybe every 2nd year as a mean

You still can use a git lfs setup... but for one (big) file.

Simply zip all the smaller binary files in a zip that you can then:

- store outside of the repo
- reference through lfs

> To create an installer additionally binary files are required

Your build script can then unzip those files on demand, and use them during the build process.

Comment: Yes, that's one possibility already considered - the binary files are sorted in 20 Groups, one zip per Group. Drawback would be for testing one has also to extract the zip file. 

Maybe this could be done with post-checkout and pre-commit hooks. (Pre-commit for the cases when any of the binary files is modified or added.)

Comment: @milbrandt yes, and those hooks can detect if the binary files have changed: if they have not: nothing to do.

Comment: Do you know of any example hook for such a use case? post-checkout I can imagine, but on first glance pre-commit seems a bit more complicated. There is no single file to compare any hash code and time stamps would not be very reliable

Comment: @milbrandt but since they change "Maybe every 2nd year", surely you can manage those updates separately, as part of a known binary update event, instead of checking every time in every cloned repo?

Comment: Yes sure, but automation is more foolproof than any manual steps :)

Comment: @milbrandt in this case, automation would run way too many time, as opposed to twice a year. I would recommend stating they are read-only, and updated separately, rather than read-write, and checked on every checkout in every client.

Comment: As proposed in a 1st step the binary files are grouped and zipped (with in some cases the size even increased slightly) and stored to git LFS. No Automation git hooks supplied for now.